# Converting Character into Date Time format in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert this character column to date time format in R, but I can't seem to stop getting null results. Can anyone help me?

I also need to separate the time and date into two different columns. First I need to convert it to date time format correct?

[picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWBxR.png)

Here's what I've tried

```
#converting date into numeric format
date_numeric <- as.numeric(minute_sleep$date) #result was null so I will delete it and try again
remove(date_numeric)

#convering date into timestamp
new_time <- strptime(minute_sleep$date, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="") #result was also null DANG IT!!
remove(new_time)

#converting date into datetime format ATTEMPT 1
new_date_column <- as.POSIXct(minute_sleep$date, format="%m/%d/%YT%H:%M:%OS") #return was also null
remove(new_date_column)

#converting date into datetime format ATTEMPT 2
date_time <- ymd_hms(minute_sleep$date) #NULL RESULTS!!!!
```

Comment: Please don't post data as an image.  Use `dput()` and paste an example of the data into your question as text.

Comment: as.POSIXct(minute_sleep$date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"),  there is no T in your data, there shouldn’t be a T in the format.

Comment: If you're using `lubridate` functions, your date format looks like it is either day/month/year or month/day/year, not year/month/day. So the correct function is either `mdy_hms()` or `dmy_hms()`, not `ymd_hms()`.